# Using data collected with axios later in the code

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to collect a data with API with axios. But let's say I want to use this data later on the code but whenever I get out of the async code the returned data's status becomes pending. How to return data and store it to use whenever I want in code?

Here is the code:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
const response = await axios.get("http://www.omdbapi.com/", {
    params: {
        apikey: "a7aeae67",
        // s: `${searchBar.value}`
        s: "vam"

    }
})
}

console.log(fetchData())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the famous ["blue function red function"](https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/) argument. Once your code is doing something `async` it will *always* need to be accessed in async context.

So - it is impossible to access `response` from a non-async function and you would have to access it inside `async` functions by `await`ing it in turn.